# How to get the latest value at each column level in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

Change data capture (CDC) records will not have all values for the columns in a record. It is possible that for a record's primary key, say ID  we can have CDC records for ID=1 with Load_Timestamp.
Ex. If Record R1 has columns Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Load_Timestamp

CDC records will be

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0AMMX.png)

Is it possible to get output as follows in bigquery ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oArxo.png)

Answer (score 0):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL 
SELECT id,
  ARRAY_AGG(COL1 IGNORE NULLS ORDER BY Load_Timestamp DESC LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)] AS COL1,
  ARRAY_AGG(COL2 IGNORE NULLS ORDER BY Load_Timestamp DESC LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)] AS COL2,
  ARRAY_AGG(COL3 IGNORE NULLS ORDER BY Load_Timestamp DESC LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)] AS COL3,
  ARRAY_AGG(COL4 IGNORE NULLS ORDER BY Load_Timestamp DESC LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)] AS COL4,
  MAX(Load_Timestamp) AS Load_Timestamp
FROM `project.dataset.table`
GROUP BY id
```

or, you can refactor above using UDF as in below example

```
#standardSQL 
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION LATEST_VALUE(arr ARRAY<STRUCT<el STRING, ts TIMESTAMP>>) AS ((
  SELECT el
  FROM UNNEST(arr)
  WHERE NOT el IS NULL
  ORDER BY ts DESC
  LIMIT 1
));
SELECT id,
  LATEST_VALUE(ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(COL1, Load_Timestamp))) AS COL1,
  LATEST_VALUE(ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(COL2, Load_Timestamp))) AS COL2,
  LATEST_VALUE(ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(COL3, Load_Timestamp))) AS COL3,
  LATEST_VALUE(ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(COL4, Load_Timestamp))) AS COL4,
  MAX(Load_Timestamp) AS Load_Timestamp
FROM `project.dataset.table`
GROUP BY id
```

Comment: While running the queries against table having size 1.4TB / 2265683330 records. Queries execution is taking more than 27 mins. Partition and Clustering will not help since to create the complete row we need to read full table. Is there any solution which we need to perform to improve query execution?